# Apply font change dynamically on xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Good afternoon. I am working on dynamic resizing and font attributes in forms.

At the moment, I have made changes to the application, but they are applied only after creating the page, but I would like to immediately.
I used the ForceLayout () method but it did not help, what else can I use?

```
    [assembly: Dependency(typeof(ChangeFontAndroid))]
namespace SpecialForcesDirectory.Droid
{
    public class ChangeFontAndroid : IScaleFont
    {
        public void Scale(float val)
        {
            var configuration = Resources.System.Configuration;
            configuration.FontScale = (float)val;
            MainActivity.AppContext.Resources.Configuration.UpdateFrom(configuration);
            MainActivity.AppContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics.ScaledDensity = configuration.FontScale * (float)DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use [DynamicResources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/dynamic).

You store these resources in your Application Resources and then use them all over the app changing them at one place will change them all over the app.

For instance, You have a font size as a double in your App.xaml:

```
 <x:Double x:Key="DefaultFontSize">20</x:Double>
 <x:Double x:Key="EnlargedFontSize">30</x:Double>
```

And you have a DynamicResource that based on conditions assigns itself some value:

```
 Resources ["DynamicFontSize"] =Condition ? Resources ["DefaultFontSize"]:Resources ["EnlargedFontSize"];
```

The above code could be anywhere on any condition, Where Resources are `Application.Current.Resources`

Then where ever you have the below code this will be changed dynamically:

```
<Label FontSize= {DynamicResource DynamicFontSize}
<Button FontSize= {DynamicResource DynamicFontSize}
```

Works on all properties that are Bindable.

Goodluck feel free to get back if you have queries.

Comment: Good solution. A i'm firstly try it. But now in project  more that 50 page and  ~400  control.

Comment: Doesn't matter it will work no matter how many pages you have you just have to use dynamic resource :)

Comment: For application no. For me yes. Many monkey job for replace xaml in many location. Find you articles, in network, very impressive.